# LazzyLoading in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

i have a a Pivot that has a ListBox defined as its Pivot.ItemTemplate as the following.

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="pivot">
 <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
   ...
   </ListBox>
  </DataTemplate>
 </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

how do i programmatically access the corresponding ListBox control corresponding to the Pivot.SelectedItem or Pivot.SelectedIndex?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using data binding i.e. are you setting `ItemsSource` on the Pivot?
 - If not, this doesn't make much sense.
 - If you do, then you cannot access it because that `ListBox` is instantiated for every pivot page from the data source and there is no *single* list box.

What you need to do here is use full data binding on the `ListBox` also. You shouldn't mix direct control access with data binding.

Try explaining what you want to do, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You Can detect which Pivot is Selected
by this Code

if You have 3 Panorama/Pivot Item's and on the OnNavigatedTo() handler, change the default item

```
pivot/panoramaControl.DefaultItem = pivot/panoramaControl.Items[indexToSet];
```